# Is use of HttpServletRequest.getQueryString() for a response header vulnerable to response splitting?

Tags: web-application, java, response-splitting

I've been told that using [`HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) in a response header makes my application susceptible to HTTP response splitting attacks, but I just don't see how.

It's clear in the case of [`getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29), which decodes percent-encoded values, but `getQueryString()` does not do that. From the documentation:

> The value is not decoded by the container.

Source code snippet illustrating what I'm doing:

```
String path = "some_url";

String qs = req.getQueryString();
if (qs != null)
    path += "?" + qs;

// response instanceof HttpServletResponse
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", path);
```

I tried to reproduce the issue, and I just get the percent-encoded newlines echoed back to me in the response. When I change the code to `getParameter(…)`, it works as expected (except that my container is nice enough to strip the newlines from the header value, but in theory at least it works). [This similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902563/does-putting-request-getquerystring-in-response-sendredirect-make-you-vulnerable) asks the same, and a comment to the answer pointing out that `getQueryString()` does not decode got no response.

Am I missing something here? Or is the advice I got wrong?

Comment: `I've been told` - Do you have a reference to where you heard it? Did someone say it after seeing or hearing about your code.

Comment: @NeilSmithline A source code analysis tool identified use of `getQueryString()` and `setHeader(…)` exactly like in the sample code snippet as the (possible) vulnerability. Unfortunately I do not want to go into more details, while that report hasn't been disproved/the vulnerability hasn't been resolved, as doing so may reveal the identity of the software that got identified as having a potential vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern of using data that comes from the user without sanitizing it is a source of vulnerabilities. Typical things like XSS and SQLi. In this case you are taking the input from the user and directly making it a header. This could lead to response splitting, header injection, and maybe another problem or two (eg: CSRF may be possible if you can inject Javascript). But you state that:

> my container is nice enough to strip the newlines from the header value

so this is preventing actual exploit.

I suspect that even if you were to filter the input such as:

```
path += "?" + sanitize(qs);
```

for an appropriate `sanitize` function (say from [OWASP's AntiSamy project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project)) that your static analyzer will continue to give you this finding. So, in the end, you're going to be marking this finding as a false positive (`Not an issue` if you're using Fortify). The only question is whether you should include a code change before marking the finding as a false positive.

My take is that if the API explicitly says that it is responsible for secure handling of newlines and other special characters, then no action is needed on your part. When I look at the Javadoc for [HttpServletResponse.setHeader](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), I see no mention of how special characters will be handled. So, unless the spec explicitly states a secure handling of this (I don't think it does but I didn't look this up in the Servlet spec), I would recommend sanitizing the input and rerunning the static scanner. If, as I expect, it continues to report this issue, then mark it a false positive and rest assured that all is well.

The reason I feel that you should only trust this behavior if it is specified in the spec is that that is the only behavior that is guaranteed. A new version of your Servlet container or another container altogether might change this behavior. It is very unlikely you would detect such a change though it would lead your site vulnerable.

Comment: I'm not asking about `getParameter(String)`, it's pretty clear how that works (I mentioned it to show that I've done some research into this topic). I'm trying to understand how `getQueryString()`, which does not decode the (presumable percent-)encoded input, poses a problem. Since I don't even understand why the tool complains, I'm not comfortable with believing it once it no longer complains without understanding the possible vulnerability. So the "satisfy the tool" approach you seem to recommend isn't exactly what I'm looking for here.